# Realise the denominator and hence find $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Question: **Realise the denominator $\frac{3+2i\sin\theta}{1-2i\sin\theta}$ and hence find $\theta$ if the expression is purely imaginary.**

I've realised the denominator $\frac{3+8i\sin\theta-4\sin^2\theta}{1+4\sin^2\theta}$ but don't know how to utilise the knowledge that the expression is purely imaginary.

Comment: `how to utilise the knowledge that the expression is purely imaginary` That means the real part of the expression is zero, which gives an equation in $\theta$.

Comment: So this is pure imaginary if the real part of the numerator, namely $2-4\sin(\theta)^2$, is zero, *n'est-ce pas*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second expression that you wrote can be written as
$$ \frac{3 + 8i\sin(\theta) - 4\sin(\theta)^2}{1+4\sin(\theta)^2}
= \underbrace{\frac{3 - 4\sin(\theta)^2}{1+4\sin(\theta)^2}}_{\text{real part}} + i\underbrace{\frac{8\sin(\theta)}{1+4\sin(\theta)^2}}_{\text{imaginary part}}. $$
If the expression is to be purely imaginary, then the real part must be zero.  This occurs only when the numerator of the real part is zero, i.e. when
$$ 3 - 4\sin(\theta)^2 = 0. $$
Via some manipulation, this becomes
$$ \sin(\theta) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\implies \theta \in \left\{ \pm \frac{\pi}{3} + 2k\pi \ \middle|\  k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} \cup \left\{ \pm \frac{2\pi}{3} + 2k\pi \ \middle|\ k\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}.$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary integer.

Comment: wow it was right under my nose :D thanks!